# Compare 2 strings in V+

Tags: v+

What is the best way to compare 2 strings for equality in V+. Is there a `strcmp` style function? Is it possible to get a value based on the `lexicographical` order of the strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strcmp function, you can do 2 things:

1. If you want a straight bool value you can use `==`:

   ```
   $in1 = "lalala"
   $in2 = "lalala"

   IF $in1 == $in2 THEN
       TYPE "LALALA"
   END
   ```
2. If you want a function that returns a number based on lexicographical order you will need to write one, something like this will suffice:

---

```
.PROGRAM strcmp($a, $b, result)
        AUTO len.a, len.b, pos

        len.a = LEN($a)
        len.b = LEN($b)
        pos = 1

        ; Loop to the end of the string that is the same
        WHILE (pos-1 < len.a) AND (pos-1 < len.b) AND (ASC($a,pos) == ASC($b,pos)) DO
            pos = pos+1
        END

        ; If they are still the same at the end return 0
        IF (ASC($a,pos) == ASC($b,pos)) THEN
            result = 0
            RETURN
        END

        ; If $a is -1 then we reached the end of a before b
        IF (ASC($a,pos) == -1) THEN
            result = -1
            RETURN
        END

        ; If $b is -1 then we reached the end of b before a
        IF (ASC($b,pos) == -1) THEN
            result = 1
            RETURN
        END

        ; Otherwise get the comparison of the current value of $a and $b
        result = ASC($a,pos)-ASC($b,pos)
        RETURN
.END
```